# Polynomial ring $F[x]$ integrally closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Question: Let $F$ be a field and $A\subset F[x]$ the polynomials without the linear term. Prove that $F[x]$ is the integral closure of $A$.

My Proof:
Since we have $x=x^3/x^2$, the field of fractions of $A$ is $F(x)$, because $x^2,x^3\in A$. Also, $x\in F(x)$ is a root of $t^2-x^2\in A[t]$, so $A$ is not integrally closed. In fact, $F[x]$ is generated by $1,\ x$ as an $A$-module, so any element of $F[x]$ is integral over $A$. And since every UFD is integrally closed, $F[x]$ is closed, hence it must be the integral closure of $A$.

But, when I take $y=\frac{x^3+2}{x^2-5}\in F(x)$, then $(x^2-5)\cdot t- (x^3+2)\in A[t]$ has $y$ as a root. So $y$ should be in the integral closure of $A$. What is my mistake?

Comment: Do you know what "integral closure" means?

Comment: I thought it meant the following: The integral closure of $A$ is every element in the fraction field of $A$ which is integral over $A$.

Comment: So why do you believe that your $y$ must be in the integral closure of $A$?

Comment: Because $y$ is in the fraction field $F(x)$ and I have found a polynomial $p(t)=(x^2-5)t-(x^3+2)$ with coefficients in $A$ such that $p(y)=0$, i.e. $y$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: So you don't know what "integral over $A$" means. Better look it up.

Comment: Oh, is it because $p(t)$ is not monic? I am silly. ^^

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments above.*

---

If $A \subset B$ are commutative rings with identity, then an element $\alpha \in B$ is said to be **integral over $A$** if $\alpha$ satisfies a *monic* polynomial $f(X) \in A[X]$, that is, a polynomial whose leading coefficient is $1$, so $f$ is of the form
$$
f(X) = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 X + a_0
$$
for some $a_i \in A$, $0 \leq i \leq n-1$.

So, since $p(t) = (x^2 - 5) \cdot t - (x^3 + 2) \in A[t]$ is not monic, $y = \frac{x^3 + 2}{x^2 - 5}$ is not integral over $A$.